# What does the "External Libraries" entry in the main project view of IntelliJ mean?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

What does the "External Libraries" entry in the main project view of IntelliJ mean?  I don't think it was there until I tried to add the Support library (v7).  Now I don't know how to remove it, or even if it's needed or not.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to remove it. The section is there to provide an easy means for devs to see what external libs are being used in the project.